# Convert function to odbc filedsn

Tags: asp.net

Classic Asp Code. I have a simple redirect function opendb that uses a DSN

`Response.Redirect("launchsearch.asp?DSN=database&Name=databasename")`

I need to convert to a fileDSN or mappath. The trouble I'm getting into is the lanchsearch.asp. Here is the code for it.

```
`dim bDbFound
bDbFound = False
Session("DbName") = ""

if not IsEmpty(Request("DSN")) then
  Session("DSN") = Request("DSN")
  bDbFound = True
end if

if not IsEmpty(Request("Name")) then
  Session("DbName") = Request("Name")
  bDbFound = True
end if

if bDbFound then
  Response.Write("<script>" & vbCrLf)
  Response.Write("parent.location.replace('searchform.asp');" & vbCrLf) 
  Response.Write("</script>")               
else
  Response.Write("Unknown database: " & Request("DbName"))
end if'
```

Comment: What's the trouble you're getting into? You have to be more specific.

Comment: The lanchsearch.asp is setup to use a system DSN. I don't have access to a system dsn on this new server. So I'm trying to get it to work using a filedsn with no luck.

Comment: What am I missing here? [code]  DB = d & ".mdb"
                Dir = Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")
                Dir = StrReverse(Dir)
                Dir = Mid(Dir, InStr(1, Dir, "/"))
                Dir = StrReverse(Dir)
                Path = Server.MapPath(Dir) & "\"
                f = "dsn.dsn"
                Set strcon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
                strcon.Open "filedsn=c:\sdidata\dsn.dsn;DBQ=c:\sdidata\database.mdb"
Response.Redirect("launchsearch.asp?DSN="&filedsn&"&Name=databasename")

Comment: thanks I got it by using a mapped path. I should have done that to start with.